# Which book by Steven Brust has "A young man without ambition is an old man waiting to be"?

Tags: quote-source, steven-brust

> [A young man without ambition is an old man waiting to be.](https://vtmolo.com/quotes-about-ambition/)

What book is this quote from? I know the author is Steven Brust.

Answer (score 5):

The quote is from Chapter Nine of *The Paths of the Dead*, the first volume of *The Viscount of Adrilankha*, by Steven Brust.

> Piro shrugged. "I have no such plans, but, whatever the Count's plans for me may be, I have no intention of staying here for-ever."
> "Ah! My lord is ambitious?"
> "Nearly."
> "So much the better."
> "Oh?"
> **"A young man without ambition is an old man waiting to be."**
> "Ah. I perceive you are a philosopher."

<sub>Source: [Google Books](https://books.google.ae/books?id=jvMf2NgCcJkC&pg=PT104&dq=A+young+man+without+ambition+is+an+old+man+waiting+to+be.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje8IL0qdjvAhWlQEEAHXhgCesQ6AEwA3oECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=A%20young%20man%20without%20ambition%20is%20an%20old%20man%20waiting%20to%20be.&f=false)</sub>